# SQLite, Exclusive Or. How do i clear a flag?

Tags: sql, sqlite

To set a flag i write `SET status=status|?` how do i clear a flag? Usually i write `SET status=status&(-1^?)` but ^ is illegal in sqlite. How do i clear a flag or use exclusive or?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There does not appear to be a xor operator for sqlite.  You can simulate it using:

```
select (~(a&b))&(a|b)
```

For example, when 1111 (15) is masked with 0100 (4):

```
select (~(15&4))&(15|4)
```

the answer is 1011 (11).  In that way you can clear flags.

Comment: cool, ~ is supported. So, is there a problem if i did `select 15&~4` instead?

Comment: Right, that'd be much better. xor is for toggle not clear like you said